# where does Jetty save files on upload temporarily?

Tags: file-upload, hdfs, embedded-jetty, apache-commons-fileupload

I have a very basic question about file upload with embedded Jetty.

When I upload a large file, I know that Jetty server buffers it somewhere. Where does this buffer exist?

Also, Is there a way to disable the buffer and stream the request data directly to a destination such as HDFS?

If we can't disable this buffering, at least I need to have a control on deleting the tmp file after the file upload is complete.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That's defined by the servlet spec `location` value found in the [`MultipartConfigElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/MultipartConfigElement.html), typically declared as an [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) annotation on the servlet you have receiving the uploaded files.